# Ajax status received but not applying next steps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a comment system in which user comments and through ajax it validates the data and sent to .php page. The problem is it receives the status=1 but does not apply the `else if` Ajax code. I am stuck here. Any suggestions or help will be highly regarded.

**AJAX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit_comment").click(function() {

            var proceed = true;

            $(" #comment_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
                $(this).css('border-color','');
                if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty
                    $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red
                    proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
                }


            });

            if(proceed)
                post_data = {
                    'user_email'        : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                    'pid'       : $('input[name=productid]').val(),
                     'msg'          : $('textarea[name=comment]').val()
                };


            $.post('comments.php', post_data, function(response){
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';

                }
                else if(response.status && response.type != 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    $(response.html).hide().insertBefore('#comment_form').slideDown();

                    $(" #comment_form textarea[required=true]").val('');
                    $("#comment_form #comment_body").slideUp();
                }
                $("#comment_form #comment_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
        });


        //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
        $("#comment_form  input[required=true], #comment_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() {
            $(this).css('border-color','');
            $("#result").slideUp();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Form**

```
<?php
   include "comment.php";
   $comments = array();
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments where product_id='$id'  ORDER BY dt LIMIT 5");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
   $comments[] = new Comment($row);
  }
    ?>
  <?php
  foreach($comments as $c){
   echo $c->markup();
     }
 ?>
  </div>
          <?php

        }
        }


        ?>
  <div class="form-style" id="comment_form">

                <div id="comment_results"></div>
                <div id="comment_body">

                        <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email?>">
                         <input type="hidden" name="productid" id="productid" value="<?php echo $pid?>" />
                         <label for="field5"><span>Comment: <span class="required">*</span></span>
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea-field" required="true"></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_comment" value="Submit"">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**comment.php**

```
<?php

class Comment
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct($row)
    {
    $this->data = $row;
    }

    public function markup()
    {     $d = &$this->data;

    // Converting the time to a UNIX timestamp:
        $d['dt'] = strtotime($d['dt']);

        // Needed for the default gravatar image:
  return '
    <div class="comment">
    <div class="name">'.$d['email'].'</div>
    <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
                <p>'.$d['body'].'</p>
            </div>
        ';
    }
    }

   ?>
```

**comments.php**

```
<?php
include("db/db.php");
include "comment.php";
if($_POST)
{

    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pid        = filter_var($_POST["pid"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $arr = array();
    //additional php validation

    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO comments(email,body,product_id) values('$user_name','$message','$pid')");

    $arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
    $arr['id'] = mysql_insert_id();
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $arr = array_map('stripslashes',$arr);

    $insertedComment = new Comment($arr);

    if(!$res)
    {

        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Cannot recieve your comment.'));
        die($output);
    }else{


       $output= json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your review','status'=>1,'html'=>$insertedComment->markup()));
echo $output;
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are talking about this line? response.status && response.type != 'error'

Comment: @Glubus yes. The code after this line does not work

Comment: Have you tried to remove  the second part of that predicate? Since you're checking for equality in the if for 'error', it's redundant to do it in the else if. Also, what gets logged when you do console.log(response.type); (before the ifs.

Comment: i tried this ` $.post('comments.php', post_data, function(response){ console.log(response.type);` but nothing print.

Comment: Can you `console.dir(response)` and tell what is there?